# SQL Server Select Statement Trim string

Tags: sql-server-2012, trim

I have the below query with `PATINDEX` where I can find the position of "Kind Regards", however I am trying to remove the string or anything following "Kind Regards".

I do not need the bold text "Good Morning, UPS to support the agent who will be doing standby weekend. **Kind Regards Me I**"

Can anyone assist, the desired result

```
"Good Morning, UPS to support the agent who will be doing standby weekend."
```

when executing a select statement

```sql
SELECT
    PATINDEX('%Kind%', 'Good Morning, UPS to support the agent who will be doing standby weekend. Kind Regards Me I' )
FROM 
    CallLog
WHERE 
    CallID = '01002429'
```

Comment: Use `LEFT` to get the left most characters based on the position of the characters or pattern. (As you have no pattern here, I would suggest `CHARINDEX` over `PATINDEX`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
select Left(ColumnName, IsNull(NullIf(PatIndex('%Kind Regards%',ColumnName),0)-1,Len(ColumnName)))
```

This will return the string to the left of *Kind Regards* or the entire string if it doesn't exist.